# Pyinstaller fails to make my file executable

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe, gspread, oauth2client

I have a gspread python file that writes into sheets.
it works when I run it but when Im trying to convert it into an .exe file using pyinstaller moudule with the command: `pyinstaller -F main.py` it builds the file successfully. becuse I have some dependencies I move the main.exe out from the dist folder to the project folder where all the dependencies are.
When Im trying to run the `main.exe` file the cmd window opens and prints this without stopping:

```
Cannot listen to an undefined element. [Caught in: Tried to listen to element of type click]

Subsequent non-fatal errors won't be logged; see https://fburl.com/debugjs.", source: https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/yi/r/wTY5qBMkTkR.js?_nc_x=Ij3Wp8lg5Kz (58)
[0219/203902.470:INFO:CONSOLE(13)] "Date was set (cloudfront.js)", source: https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/secure-konimbo/public/data/cloudfront/javascripts/cloudfront.js?v=1645294790 (13)
[0219/203902.504:INFO:CONSOLE(22)] "cloudfront.js v35 (document - ready)", source: https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/secure-konimbo/public/data/cloudfront/javascripts/cloudfront.js?v=1645294790 (22)
[0219/203902.521:INFO:CONSOLE(13594)] "margin-top 62", source: https://www.myperfume.co.il/155569-%D7%9B%D7%9C-%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%92%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%94?order=up_title&page=3 (13594)
[0219/203902.525:INFO:CONSOLE(13594)] "right 0", source: https://www.myperfume.co.il/155569-%D7%9B%D7%9C-%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%92%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%94?order=up_title&page=3 (13594)
[0219/203902.525:INFO:CONSOLE(13594)] "left auto", source: https://www.myperfume.co.il/155569-%D7%9B%D7%9C-%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%92%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%94?order=up_title&page=3 (13594)
[0219/203902.553:INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "%c[IND]%c You are running %cWindows%c Operating system, %cChrome%c browser, version: %c98 color: White; background: #17384c; font-weight: bold; padding: 3px; border-radius:3px 0 0 3px; color: Black; background: #50e590; font-weight: bold; padding: 3px color: White; background: #17384c; font-weight: bold; padding: 3px; color: Black; background: #50e590; font-weight: bold; padding: 3px color: White; background: #17384c; font-weight: bold; padding: 3px; color: Black; background: #50e590; font-weight: bold; padding: 3px color: White; background: #17384c; font-weight: bold; padding: 3px; border-radius:0 3px 3px 0", source: https://js.nagich.co.il/core/3.0.0/accessibility.js (1)
[0219/203902.553:INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "%c[IND]%c Version %c3.0.0%c color: White; background: #17384c; font-weight: bold; padding: 3px; border-radius:3px 0 0 3px; color: Black; background: #50e590; font-weight: bold; padding: 3px color: White; background: #17384c; font-weight: bold; padding: 3px; border-radius:0 3px 3px 0 ", source: https://js.nagich.co.il/core/3.0.0/accessibility.js (1)
```

Does anyone knows how to deal with this?(I thinks it has something to do with the oauoth2client library)

Comment: If this is driving a Google Sheets file, why are there references to https://www.myperfume.co.il?

Comment: I made a program that reads some data from this accout and then putting it in a sheets file

Comment: Instead of moving .exe file from dist folder try moving all dependencies to the dist folder.

Comment: doesnt work neither

Comment: Here's the thing.  There's SO much you aren't telling us. The error you show is coming from the jQuery Javascript library.  How is Javascript involved?  Are you using Selenium?